# Finding object center: showing wrong coordinate outside of the target object

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, image-processing, scikit-image

I followed the code in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37519238/python-find-center-of-object-in-an-image) to find the object center for my graylevel image,

```
def find_center(im):
    immat = im
    (X, Y) = [im.shape[0],im.shape[1]]
    m = np.zeros((X, Y))

    for x in range(X):
        for y in range(Y):
            m[x, y] = immat[(x, y)] != 0
    m = m / np.sum(np.sum(m))


    # marginal distributions
    dx = np.sum(m, 1)
    dy = np.sum(m, 0)

    # expected values
    cx = np.sum(dx * np.arange(X))
    cy = np.sum(dy * np.arange(Y))
    return [cx,cy]

xy1=find_center(img)  #img is a binary image, object has value==1 and back ground value of 0
print xy1
plt.imshow(img)
plt.annotate('center', xy1, xycoords='data',
             xytext=(0.5, 0.5), textcoords='figure fraction',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
plt.show()
```

However, I am not getting the right answer (the center is not inside the object), the following image shows the output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like if the image was rotated by 180 degrees then the centre would be correct.

Comment: On that note, `im.shape[0]` returns image height, not width, so you perhaps are meaning to assign it to `Y` instead of `X`.

Comment: @101 it does not make any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the function `find_center` is computing the center coordinates correctly. There is a much more elegant and efficient way to perform this calculation though (see the snippet below).

The problem is that you are passing `xy1`, i.e. `[cx, cy]` to `plt.annotate`, but you need to pass `[cy, cx]`. If you change your code to `xy1 = find_center(img)[::-1]` the issue should be fixed.

Give this code a try:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

triskele = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/fczjh.png')
img = triskele > 0

[cx, cy] = np.transpose(np.nonzero(img)).mean(axis=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax.axis('off')
ax.add_patch(Circle((cy, cx), radius=12, color='red'))
plt.show(fig)
```

[image: Center position]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is working very well and it is very efficient :)